# Getting accelerometer data from Jawbone

Tags: data-extraction, jawbone

So I have a Jawbone Up band and i am trying to analyse the accelerometer data from the band. The CVS that i can download from the website does not give me that. Is there a way to extract the exact accelerometer values that the band is recording?

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37305316/1541997) posted on your other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting accelerometer data from Microsoft Band](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166241/extracting-accelerometer-data-from-microsoft-band)