# Extracting accelerometer data from Microsoft Band

Tags: accelerometer, microsoft-band, fitbit, jawbone

I am trying to do an analysis of data from various fitness tracker devices and i need to extract the accelerometer data from microsoft band jaw bone and Basis Peak for this. 
I know they have the analyzed data in their app, so the data must be somewhere on my phone, but how do i access it?
Does someone know how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Jawbone does not provide a way to access the raw accelerometer data. However, you can programmatically access the events (e.g., steps, sleep, heartrate) generated from the aggregated accelerometer data by using the [Jawbone UP API](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/).

Answer (score 1):

It is not stored on the phone in an accessible way. You need to use the band api to communicate directly with the band and subscribe to this data.

Answer (score 1):

As for Microsoft Band you can use SDK to get live accelerometer data from the device:

> The Microsoft Band SDK gives developers access to the sensors available on the Band

[MicrosoftHealth SDK website](https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK)

Answer (score 1):

How to subscribe to sensor data is described in the Microsoft Band SDK documentation. You should refer to section 5 "Subscribing to Band Sensors" (page 17).

The documentation can be found here: 
https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf